# Easy way to set face colors with indexed VBOs?

Tags: opengl, vbo, color

I'm loading OBJs, which lend themselves well to setting up as indexed VBOs, since each vertex is only defined once and then a face definition will reference the same vertex more than once when they share an edge. I want to define face colors based on the materials loaded from the OBJ. This is quite easy in immediate mode, but I've realized that using VBOs will require me to duplicate each vertex in order to have two adjacent faces with different colors. What's the best way to go about solving this without duplicating vertices?

**EDIT:** Code (LWJGL)

```
//Get the VBO from the GPU
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
//Tell OpenGL what to expect from the VBO
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, Vertex.SIZE * 4, 0); //Location
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, Vertex.SIZE * 4, 4 * 3); //Texture Coord
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, Vertex.SIZE * 4, 4 * 3 + 4 * 2); //Normal

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, size, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Comment: You could store the color inside each face and render each in a separate draw call. Then set a uniform in the shader that is the face color for each draw (assuming you are using shaders).

Comment: I am using shaders, but how would I access each face when I'm using `glDrawElements()` with my `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` and the indices of each vertex?

Comment: Instead of drawing all, you can set an uniform, draw one face, move to the next, repeat. To draw a single face, use either the last parameter of `glDrawElements` (the "offset") or you can also try [`glDrawElementsBaseVertex`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glDrawElementsBaseVertex)

Comment: However, if you really need a single color per face, then it is probably better to duplicate that color in the vertex, as performing one draw call per face is quite inefficient, as you might have imagined.

Comment: It looks like my only option is to duplicate the vertex.

Comment: In OpenGL, vertices are only duplicates if **every** vertex attribute is the same: positions, texture coords, normals, colors, and any other custom attribs in use.  You can't index some attributes but not others, or use multiple indices.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20151224151753/https://www.tartley.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/opengl-draw-calls.png